# Why is an additional 6 elements added to the javascript array

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I'm studying javascript, I decided to practice with the output of a json array in the DOM, but switching the posts page at the first click adds an extra 6 elements (copying the very first ones in the array), why is this happening?

I would like to figure out what the matter is, I'm overwriting the array so that it starts not with 1 id, but with the last one

[image]
[image]

```
 const postsList = document.querySelector('.posts-list');
 const next = document.querySelector('.next');
 const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');

let PostsList = [];
let CurrentPage = 1;


document.addEventListener('domcontentloaded', DisplayPosts(1));

async function DisplayPosts(PageNumber) {
let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

if (response.ok) {

    let request = await response.json();

    for (var i = request.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        PostsList.push(request[i]);
    }

    console.log(PostsList);
    PostsList = PostsList.slice((PageNumber - 1) * 6, PageNumber * 6);

    for(key in PostsList) {
        let PostEl = `
            <div class="post">
                <p>${PostsList[key].id}</p>
                <p>${PostsList[key].title}</p>
                <p>${PostsList[key].body}</p>
            </div>
        `;
        postsList.innerHTML += PostEl;
    }
    //console.log(PostsList)
    CurrentPage = PageNumber;
    if (CurrentPage == 1) {
        prev.classList.add('disabled');
    } else if ( PostsList.length < 6 ) {
        next.classList.add('disabled');
    } else {
        prev.classList.remove('disabled');
        next.classList.remove('disabled');
    }
} 
else {
    alert("Error HTTP: " + response.status);
}

}

next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    postsList.innerHTML = ''
    CurrentPage = CurrentPage + 1;
    DisplayPosts(CurrentPage);
})
prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
    postsList.innerHTML = ''
    CurrentPage = CurrentPage - 1;
    DisplayPosts(CurrentPage);
})
```

Comment: `PostsList` is closed upon - so its a global - and you aren't clearing it out

Comment: @Daniel A. White

Thank you, moved to the function and everything worked